# Correr 2 macros en Paralelo

Tags: excel

Tengo 2 libros distintos con macros que son las mismas, pero introduciendo parametros distintos. Mi pregunta es, como puedo ejecutarlos a la vez, es decir, se que si los abres en sesiones distintas, si que se pueden ejecutar a la vez (por ejemplo, me pasa que si ejecuto una macro, y mientras se esta ejecutando, abro un libro, lo abre en una sesion distinta, es decir, si haces ctrl+Tab, no te cambia entre los libros). ¿Como puedo abrir 2 sesiones distintas de excel de manera intencionada?

Gracias!

un saludo!

Comment: [Abrir un segundo libro de otra copia de Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/abrir-un-segundo-libro-de-otra-copia-de-excel-921fa0db-cfc5-4548-8cd5-80e6333307d8)

Comment: Hmm esta solucion parece que solo funciona con office 2013, yo tengo 2016 y no me funciona. Gracias!